# Acrylic DNS Hosts not refresh

Tags: windows-8, dns, apache-http-server, localhost

I've installed current version (0.9.31) acrylic DNS on Windows 8 machine and set DNS address to 127.0.0.1 in TCP/IP v4 settings. Then I added in ArcylicHosts entry:

```
127.0.0.1 *.dev
```

for wildcards.

But now I can't modify hosts file - if I enter some records and remove *dev entry, after restart DNS service nothing change. I tried to use purge cache file, restart PC too.

Even if I reinstall Acrylic software, the record *dev is still set, because I have response from ping to any *dev domain.

Does anyone has any idea to refresh ArcylicHosts.txt file?
Please answer me.

Comment: Can confirm that the same is happening on Windows 10. I think Acrylic DNS is basically outdated and hence dysfunctional by now.

Answer (score 2):

The AcrylicHosts.txt file is reloaded each time the Acrylic service starts.

AFAIK the only other caches involved are the DNS client cache, which can be invalidated by the 1ipconfig /flushdns1 command, and, eventually, your browser's own DNS cache.

For example in Chrome you can access its contents by navigating to:

```
chrome://net-internals/#dns
```

Comment: But I've restarted my computer and flush dns manually from windows console, so Arcylichosts.txt should be reloaded. It is not a problem with browser cache, because I've checked it from CMD>ping something.dev and there is response every time. I think it is a problem with cache in Windows 8, but I can't refresh it.